# qmlplugindump error when building with MinGW 64bits (Qt 5.13.1)

Tags: qt, qml

I built an extension plugin in release mode with **MinGW 32bits (Qt 5.13.1)**.
When I run `qmlplugindump` everything works as expected and my .qmltypes file is well generated.

But when I build my plugin in release mode with **MinGW 64bits (Qt 5.13.1)** the `qmlplugindump` leads to the following error:

```
17:10:24: Starting: "C:\Qt\QtFramework\5.13.1\mingw73_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" -nonrelocatable NXSharedControllers 1.0 ...\NXSharedControllers > NXSharedControllers\nxsharedcontrollers.qmltypes

QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Users/Documents/Qt_Main-d_5_13_1_MinGW_64bit/NX_SharedControllers/typelist.qml:3:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "NXSharedControllers": Cannot load library C:\Users\Documents\Qt_Main-d_5_13_1_MinGW_64bit\NX_SharedControllers\NXSharedControllers\NXSharedControllersPlugin.dll: Unknown error 0x000000c1.
17:10:24: The process "C:\Qt\QtFramework\5.13.1\mingw73_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project Qt_Main (kit: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Custom Process Step"
```

Does it mean anything to someone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this issue. A dependency file was missing from the plugin build folder. I created a custom target with QMake in order to copy the dependency file to this folder.